# Perl uninitialized warnings

Tags: perl, unix

I've got my program `keymap` (it is not yet actually mapping any keys yet and is currently only printing out what it sees in hex) here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode 4;
END {
    ReadMode 0; # Reset tty mode before exiting
}

if ($ARGV[0] ~~ ["h", "-h", "--help", "help"]) {
    print "Usage: (h|-h|--help|help)|(code_in codes_out [code_in codes_out]+)\nNote: output codes can be arbitrary length";
    exit;
}

$#ARGV % 2 or die "Even number of args required.\n";

$#ARGV >= 0 or warn "No args provided. Output should be identical to input.\n";

my $interactive = -t STDIN;

my %mapping = @ARGV;

{
    local $| = 1;
    my $key;
    while (ord(($key = ReadKey(0))) != 0) {
        printf("saw \\x%02X\n",ord($key));
        if ($interactive and ord($key) == 4) {
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what happens:

```
slu@new-host:~/util 20:50:20
❯ keymap a b
saw \x61
saw \x62
saw \x04
```

There I had typed on my keyboard <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

```
slu@new-host:~/util 20:50:24
❯ echo "^D^Da" | keymap
No args provided. Output should be identical to input.
saw \x04
saw \x04
saw \x61
saw \x0A
Use of uninitialized value $key in ord at /Users/slu/util/keymap line 30.
```

I'm wondering what the meaning of this is. Is it simply a case of Perl "not counting" the loop condition as "setting" `$key`? Is there some sort of thing I can do to suppress the warning here? I know about `no warnings "uninitialized";`, I don't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a known bug that warnings issued by the condition expression of a `while` loop can be misattributed to the statement in the loop evaluated just before the while condition.

The code issuing the warning is actually the condition of the `while` loop, `ord(($key = ReadKey(0))) != 0`.

`ReadKey(0)` is returning `undef`, and you are trying to get the `ord` or it.

```
while (1) {
    my $key = ReadKey(0);
    last if !defined($key) || ord($key) == 0;

    printf("saw \\x%02X\n",ord($key));

    last if $interactive and ord($key) == 4;
}
```

Comment: Would changing the line to say `while (ord(($key = ReadKey(0)))) {` address it?

Comment: No, you have to first check if `$key` is defined before invoking `ord` on it.

Comment: ( Or use [`use syntax qw( loop ); loop { ... }`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax::Feature::Loop) instead of `while (1) { ... }` :) )

Comment: Cool, thanks. Stuffing logic into while conditions isn't usually a good idea anyway.

Comment: (A logic expression is exactly what a while condition must be, so your wording is confusing)

Comment: `while (defined($key = ReadKey(0)) && ord($key) != 0) {` should do also. As `ord($key)` is used three times, you could also declare a `$kcode` and use `while (defined($key = ReadKey(0)) && ($kcode = ord($key)) != 0) {` (using `$kcode` in the loop).

Comment: @U. Windl, That doesn't compile using `use strict;`, and leaks two loop variables to the larger scope. And all while including two assignments in a condition, something that's largely avoided for lack of readability. There's a really good reason I didn't post that!

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote that from my mind, but still I cannot see why it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @U. Windl, Use of `$key` (and `$kcode`) without first declaring them. To fix the issues, you'd need `{ my ( $key, $kcode ); while ( defined( $key = ReadKey(0) ) && ( $kcode = ord($key) ) != 0 ) { ... } }`, which is a line longer than what I posted and a lot more complex.

Comment: @ikegami Honestly: I was expecting everyone who programs in Perl to change `my $key = ReadKey(0);` to `my $key;` (when it's set in the loop later), and to understand what "also declare a $kcode" means.

Comment: @U. Windl  Re "*I was expecting everyone who programs in Perl to change `my $key = ReadKey(0);` to `my $key;`*", Why would they do that? That would break the program. /// Re "*I was expecting everyone who programs in Perl to understand what "also declare a $kcode" means.*", You're the one who asked!?

Comment: @ikegami: As it seems you are not willing to understand I give up: "while (1) { my $key =ReadKey(0); ..." and "my $key; while (defined($key = ReadKey(0)) ..." is equivalent for the purpose of the example IMHO.

Comment: @U. Windl, If they're equivalent, then why did you say anything at all. Your own actions are traitorous. Your version leaks `$key` and `$kcode` to the surrounding scope, and makes the code harder to read. There's a good reason I didn't use your version!